# Graphql query does not return image for gatsby-image but works in graphiQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am building a blog with multiple `gatsby-source-filesystem` instances.

I am trying to use gatsby-image on a page but it simply returns:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixed' of undefined`

The image I'm trying to query is located at src/images

**spirits.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import Paper from '../components/paper'


const SpiritsPage = ({data}) => (
        <Layout>
            <SEO title="Spirits" />
            <Paper>
                <h1>Spirits</h1>
                <p>This section is still under construction.</p>
                <Img fixed={data.allImageSharp.edges.node.fixed} alt />
            </Paper>
        </Layout>
    )

export const query = graphql`
    query {
        allImageSharp(filter: {fluid: {originalName: {eq: "australia.png"}}}) {
            edges {
                node {
                    fixed {
                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

`

export default SpiritsPage
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
{
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `distilleries`,
                path: `${__dirname}/content/distilleries`,
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `images`,
                path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `posts`,
                path: `${__dirname}/content/posts`
            },
        },
        `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
```

Comment: `data.alImageSharp.edges` is an array, so you can't do `data.allImageSharp.edges.node`. Instead, what you need to do is grab the item you want from the `edges` array and then do `node.fixed` on it. Something like the following would work: `data.allImageSharp.edges[0].node.fixed`

Comment: Of course! That's solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.alImageSharp.edges` is an array, so you can't do `data.allImageSharp.edges.node`. Instead, what you need to do is grab the item you want from the `edges` array and then do `node.fixed` on it. Something like the following would work: `data.allImageSharp.edges[0].node.fixed`

credit – goto1